# cannot be diligent

Tags: modal-verbs, can-modal

Someone told me "cannot" isn't used properly in the following because it means "incapable or unwilling." Do you think it's incorrectly used? I saw it being used to talk about impossibility.

> Mary **cannot** be diligent. She always chats when working.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided no context for this statement. As we don't know what conversation is going on, it is difficult to pin down the exact meaning.

However emphasis is important. The meaning depends partly on whether we emphasise "can" or "not". This determines whether we use "can not" or "cannot".

Mary can **not** be diligent.  (probably impossibility depending on context)

is different from

Mary **can**not be diligent. (probably unwillingness depending on context)

Comment: Are you suggesting that the different spellings signify different meanings?

Comment: We can say that someone "cannot be" something to say that they are incapable of being in a particular state, e.g. a child cannot be still, silent, etc. You could add 'ever' to resolve ambiguity for example "he cannot ever be serious".

Comment: @Apollyon - Not quite. I am suggesting that different emphasis requires different spelling and that such different emphasis will be determined by the context and the intention of the speaker. Here's a passage that uses "can not" repeatedly and then "cannot" once. It starts with "You can not trust a priest..." and ends with "...cannot steal your identity. WHY?" https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ol1vAT_jLuMC&pg=PA4&dq=%22can+not%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLlqjZrJPtAhWOYMAKHbcVARkQ6AEwCXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22can%20not%22&f=false

Comment: If I want to say something is impossible, it it okay to say "he/she cannot be . . . "?

Comment: @Apollyon - I think we need to see what others say. I'm not sure how to explain it. In British English we would say "Mary *can't* be diligent. She always chats when working."  This would mean that it is impossible for Mary to be diligent *because* she always chats.  Maybe I'll come back to this question at a later date with fresh eyes.

Comment: I suspect that some Americans don't make that distinction and treat "cannot" and "can't" as equivalents that differ only in degrees of formality. https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cannot-be-diligent.3764640/#post-19223887